# método não aplicado em java

Tags: java, lógica

Estou fazendo um programa para cadastrar dados de uma locadora de filmes, onde cada registro é composto pelo nome do filme, pelo gênero e pelo código do filme, usando métodos e vetores. Ele possui 3 arquivos:

***1. Código principal***

```
package Atividades;

import java.util.Scanner;
import Atividades.Filme;
import application.AlunoVet;

public class AlunoVetMain {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        char opcao;
        
        LocadoraVet Locadora = new LocadoraVet();

        do {
            System.out.println("[1]Cadastrar Filme" + "\n[2]Consultar Filmes por gênero"
                    + "\n[3]Excluir filme do arquivo pelo nome\n[4]Sair");
            opcao = scan.next().charAt(0);
            switch (opcao) {
            case '1':
                cadastrarFilme(Locadora);
                break;
            case '2':
                consultarFilmes(Locadora);
                break;
            case '3':
                System.out.println("c");
                break;
            case '4':
                System.out.println("Fim das operações");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção Inválida. Tente novamente");
            }
        } while (opcao != '4');

        
    }

     static void cadastrarFilme(LocadoraVet t) {
        Filme filme = new Filme();
        String nome;
        char genero;
        int codigo;
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do filme: ");
        nome = scan.next(); 
        System.out.println("Digite o gênero do filme:"
                + "\n[T]Terror"
                + "\n[D]Drama"
                + "\n[A]Ação");
        genero = scan.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Digite o código do flme:");
        codigo = scan.nextInt();
    }
     
    
    
    
    static void consultarFilmes(LocadoraVet t) {
        int posicao;
        char genero;
        System.out.println("Digite a matricula do aluno:");
        genero = scan.next().charAt(0);
        posicao = t.consultarFilmes(genero);
        if (posicao == t.getQuantVetor()) {
            System.out.println("o aluno não foi encontrado.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(t.getVetor(posicao));
        }
    }
            
    }
```

***2. A classe com os `atributos`, construtores e `getters` e `setters`:***

```
package Atividades;

public class Filme {
    private String nome;
    private char genero;
    private int codigo;

    public Filme() {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public char getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(char genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void Codigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Filme [nome=" + nome + ", genero=" + genero + ", codigo=" + codigo + "]";
    }
    
}
```

*E a classe do vetor com seu `construtor`, `getters` e `setters` e onde eu guardo os métodos das operações:*

```
package Atividades;

import application.Aluno;

public class LocadoraVet {
    private Filme[] vetor;
    private char quantVetor;
    
    public LocadoraVet() {
        this.vetor = vetor;
        this.quantVetor = quantVetor;
    }

    public Filme[] getVetor() {
        return vetor;
    }

    public void setVetor(Filme[] vetor) {
        this.vetor = vetor;
    }

    public char getQuantVetor() {
        return quantVetor;
    }

    public void setQuantVetor(char quantVetor) {
        this.quantVetor = quantVetor;
    }
    
    // inserir um aluno no objeto vetor
        public boolean cadastrarFilme(Filme novo) {
            if (this.quantVetor == this.vetor.length) {// saber se o arquivo cheio
                return false;
            } else {
                this.vetor[this.quantVetor] = novo;
                this.quantVetor++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        
        // pesquisar a posição de um aluno no vetor
        public char consultarFilmes(char genero) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.quantVetor; i++) {
                if (this.vetor[i].getCodigo() == genero) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return this.quantVetor;
        }   
            
}
```

Estou fazendo o método para consultar os filmes de um determinado gênero. O gênero é informado pela `letra` *( `[T]Terror`, `[D]Drama`, `[A]Ação` )* e uso a tipo primitivo `char`, no método `consultarFilmes(LocadoraVet t)`  o filme está dando erro, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -1):

```
public char consultarFilmes(char genero) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.quantVetor; i++) {
            if (this.vetor[i].getCodigo() == genero) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return this.quantVetor;
    }
```

Voce esta retornando um int nao um char;

Para corrigir

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlunoVetMain {
   static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Integer index = 0;
       Filme[] filmes= new Filme[100];
       char opcao;


       LocadoraVet Locadora = new LocadoraVet(filmes, index);

       do {
           System.out.println("[1]Cadastrar Filme" + "\n[2]Consultar Filmes por gênero"
                   + "\n[3]Excluir filme do arquivo pelo nome\n[4]Sair");
           opcao = scan.next().charAt(0);
           switch (opcao) {
               case '1':
                   cadastrarFilme(Locadora);
                   break;
               case '2':
                   consultarFilmes(Locadora);
                   break;
               case '3':
                   System.out.println("c");
                   break;
               case '4':
                   System.out.println("Fim das operações");
                   break;
               default:
                   System.out.println("Opção Inválida. Tente novamente");
           }
       } while (opcao != '4');


   }

   static void cadastrarFilme(LocadoraVet t) {
       Filme filme = new Filme();
       System.out.println("Digite o nome do filme: ");
       String nome = scan.next();
       System.out.println("Digite o gênero do filme:"
               + "\n[T]Terror"
               + "\n[D]Drama"
               + "\n[A]Ação");
       char genero = scan.next().charAt(0);
       System.out.println("Digite o código do flme:");
       int codigo = scan.nextInt();

       t.cadastrarFilme(new Filme(nome,genero,codigo));

   }




   static void consultarFilmes(LocadoraVet t) {
       char genero;
       System.out.println("Informe o Genero :   +" +
               " \n[T]Terror" +
               " \n[D]Drama" +
               " \n[A]Ação");
       genero = scan.next().charAt(0);
       System.out.println(genero);
       try{
           var filme = t.consultarFilmes(genero);
           System.out.println(filme.getNome());
       }catch (FilmeNaoExisteException ex){
           System.out.println("Filme nao existe");
       }

   }
}
```

```
    
public class Filme {
    private String nome;
    private char genero;
    private int codigo;

    public Filme() {
    }

    public Filme(String nome, char genero, int codigo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public char getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(char genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void Codigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Filme [nome=" + nome + ", genero=" + genero + ", codigo=" + codigo + "]";
    }
    
}
```

```
    public class FilmeNaoExisteException extends RuntimeException{

    public FilmeNaoExisteException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```
    public class LocadoraVet {
    private Filme[] vetor;
    Integer index;

    public LocadoraVet() {
        this.vetor = new Filme[30];
    }

    public LocadoraVet(Filme[] vetor, Integer index) {
        this.vetor = vetor;
        this.index = index;
    }

    // inserir um aluno no objeto vetor
        public Filme cadastrarFilme(Filme novo) {
            this.vetor[index] = novo;
            index++;
            return novo;
        }
        
        
        // pesquisar a posição de um aluno no vetor
        public Filme consultarFilmes(char genero) {
            if (this.vetor.length==0){
                throw new FilmeNaoExisteException("nao existe nenhum filme");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.vetor.length; i++) {
                if (this.vetor[i].getGenero() == genero) {
                    return this.vetor[i];
                }
            }
            throw new FilmeNaoExisteException("Filme nao encontrado");
        }   
            
}
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado pela atenção, tá funcionando normal

Comment: mas agora quando eu cadastro 2 filmes, quando vou consultar os filmes por gênero só aparece o primeiro filme cadastrado, o segundo não aparece, sabe o que pode ser isso?

Comment: Vc precisa retornar a lista de filmes, Recomendo vc utilizar um list em vez de array puro e criar um filter https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-filter-lambda